# What is the algorithm for Shannon-Fano code? am I correct?

Tags: algorithms, coding-theory

I am wondering what is the true algorithm for the Shannon-Fano code? The the result I am getting based on the Algorithm in [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Fano_coding#Shannon.E2.80.93Fano_Algorithm) contradicts the supposed/expected length of the produced code. According to the proof of Kraft's inequality,  $l_i = \lceil \log_2{\frac{1}{P_i}} \rceil= \lceil -\log_2{P_i} \rceil$.

> A Shannon–Fano tree is built according to a specification designed to
>   define an effective code table. The actual algorithm is simple:
>
> 1. For a given list of symbols, develop a corresponding list of
>      probabilities or frequency counts so that each symbol’s relative
>      frequency of occurrence is known.
> 2. Sort the lists of symbols according to frequency, with the most
>          frequently occurring symbols at the left and the least common at the
>          right.
> 3. Divide the list into two parts, with the total frequency counts of
>          the left part being as close to the total of the right as possible.
> 4. The left part of the list is assigned the binary digit 0, and the
>          right part is assigned the digit 1. This means that the codes for
>          the symbols in the first part will all start with 0, and the codes
>          in the second part will all start with
> 5. Recursively apply the steps 3 and 4 to each of the two halves,
>          subdividing groups and adding bits to the codes until each symbol
>          has become a corresponding code leaf on the tree.

*For example:*

$S_1 \rightarrow P_{S_1} = \frac{4}{9} \rightarrow Code = 0 \mapsto$ And: $\lceil \log_2{\frac{9}{4}}\rceil = 2 \neq 1$ Bad!

$S_2 \rightarrow P_{S_2} = \frac{2}{9} \rightarrow Code = 10 \mapsto$ And: $\lceil \log_2{\frac{9}{2}}\rceil = 3 \neq 2$ Bad!

$S_3 \rightarrow P_{S_3} = \frac{2}{9} \rightarrow Code = 110 \mapsto$ But: $\lceil \log_2{\frac{9}{2}}\rceil = 3 = 3$

$S_4 \rightarrow P_{S_4} = \frac{1}{9} \rightarrow Code = 111 \mapsto$ And: $\lceil \log_2{\frac{9}{1}}\rceil = 4 \neq 3$ Bad!

We can see that the length of produced Shannon-Fano code is $1$, but it supposed to be $2$. Which mean this algorithm is not correct. What is correct algorithm then?

**Additional note:** If we look at the example 1 of [this](http://site.iugaza.edu.ps/jroumy/files/Shanon-Fano.pdf) document, we can see that the length of $A4$ is supposed to be $3$ not $4$. The same contradiction. [Another contradiction in example 1 of this other document](http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/sqc/EL334N/InfThe-Rev.pdf). I think it is clear what I am talking about.

**More additional note:**
Here is the page 45 of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852336226) textbook -Information and Coding Theory (Springer Undergraduate Mathematics Series) 2000th Edition
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing "Shannon coding" from "Shannon–Fano coding" (terminology could vary across sources). Per Wikipedia, Shannon–Fano coding is the algorithm you mention, while Shannon coding is any coding assigning a symbol occurring with probability $p_i$ a codeword of length $\ell_i = \lceil \log_2 \frac{1}{p_i} \rceil$. Per Wikipedia, Shannon–Fano coding always leads to codewords whose lengths are within one bit of $\log_2 \frac{1}{p_i}$. This is also a feature of Shannon coding, but the two need not be the same. In particular, Shannon–Fano coding always saturates the Kraft–McMillan inequality, while Shannon coding doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is clear now. I was watching some youtube turorial videos, Do you think this is correct approach to find Shannon coding? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ztAuu2zFutM

Comment: I don't know, but now you have all the information you need to answer this question yourself.